# HTTPS AppStrip code?

Tags: https, facebook-canvas

Does anyone working with AppStrip have a code to call the AppStrip bar via HTTPS? I'm hoping to have something up to test next week before the Oct. 1 migration deadline, but they haven't updated their site with the code yet. Last I heard something was supposed to be up this week. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppStrip has update the code on their web site. In the interest of not disclosing their code outside of the partners they accept, I won't post it here, but if you are using the AppStrip bar you can find it on their web site.

Log in to AppStrip.com, choose 'Applications', click 'Code' next to one of your applications in the list, and you will see that the codes have been updated to be compliant with the SSL migration.